# How to check if a date field in a row is older than the previous row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table with some transactions with the ID, date and amount:

| TransID | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1494808 | 2022-06-04 16:44:56.700 | 50 |
| 1494809 | 2022-06-04 15:44:56.700 | 60 |

See transactionID  1494809, the date is older than 1494808. Basically, what I need is to do a search for transactions like this in the table and then insert it into a temp table so the customer can track these weird transactions in the system. Which is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Hint: `LAG`/`LEAD`.

Comment: `select * from (select t.*, lag(date) over(order by transid) as prev_date from t) x where date < prev_date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LAG` (or `LEAD`) to compare rows' values, like so:

```sql
WITH withLag AS (

    SELECT
        TransId,
        "Date",
        Amount,
        LAG( TransId, 1, NULL ) OVER ( ORDER BY TransId ) AS PrevTransId,
        LAG( "Date" , 1, NULL ) OVER ( ORDER BY TransId ) AS PrevTransDate,
        LAG( Amount , 1, NULL ) OVER ( ORDER BY TransId ) AS PrevAmount
    FROM
        table
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    withLag
WHERE
    PrevTransId < TransId
    AND
    PrevTransDate > "Date"
ORDER BY
    TransId
```

---

SQLFiddle.com: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e0811/4

Screenshot proof:

[image]

Comment: I think the predicate `PrevTransId < TransId` is always true and could be omitted.

Comment: I found an issue when more than one of the subsequent transactions are with the incorrect date, the query will only consider the first one and will not show all the incorrect data, please check: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1f374/1